# Why pre increment is not evaluated

Tags: c, logical-operators, pre-increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a=5,b=-7,c=0,d;
    d=++a && ++b || ++c;
    printf("%d %d %d %d",a,b,c,d);
}
```

Here value of c should increase to 1 but it is giving 0, why?

Comment: [(Boolean) Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) strikes again.

Comment: I can only guess it's because of the `||` operator which doesn't execute since the first part `&&` is already `true` so the value of `|| ++c` doesn't matter.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović Why guess?

Comment: @EugeneSh Because I'm unsure of how it works myself, just using the logic and knowledge of what I know.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović Take a look at the standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13p4 and you won't have to guess anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

It's because of short-circuiting.  If you have `a && b`, then `b` will only be evaluated if `a` is true.  Similarly, if you have `a || b`, then `b` will only be evaluated if `a` is false.

In your case, `++a && ++b || ++c` groups as `(++a && ++b) || ++c`.  First `++a` is evaluated, and it's true, so `++b` is evaluated, and it's also true.  At this point, evaluation stops because it is now certain that the result of the `||` operator is true, so `++c` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Because the || doesn't evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side evaluated to true. In your example,

```
++a && ++b
```

evaluates to non-zero, which is treated as a true. Therefore, according to the rules of lazy evaluation, the `++c` is completely ignored.